# Weighted mse custom loss function in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I'm working with time series data, outputting 60 predicted days ahead.

I'm currently using mean squared error as my loss function and the results are bad

I want to implement a weighted mean squared error such that the early outputs are much more important than later ones.

**Weighted Mean Square Root formula:**

[image: Weighted Mean Square Root formula]

So I need some way to iterate over a tensor's elements, with an index (since I need to iterate over both the predicted and the true values at the same time, then write the results to a tensor with only one element. They're both (?,60) but really (1,60) lists.

And nothing I'm trying is working. Here's the code for the broken version

```
def weighted_mse(y_true,y_pred):
    wmse = K.cast(0.0,'float')

    size = K.shape(y_true)[0]
    for i in range(0,K.eval(size)):
        wmse += 1/(i+1)*K.square((y_true[i]-y_pred)[i])

    wmse /= K.eval(size)
    return wmse
```

I am currently getting this error as a result:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_2_target' with dtype float
 [[Node: dense_2_target = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Having read the replies to similar posts, I don't think a mask can accomplish the task, and looping over elements in one tensor would also not work since I'd not be able to access the corresponding element in the other tensor.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this approach:

```
def weighted_mse(yTrue,yPred):

    ones = K.ones_like(yTrue[0,:]) #a simple vector with ones shaped as (60,)
    idx = K.cumsum(ones) #similar to a 'range(1,61)'


    return K.mean((1/idx)*K.square(yTrue-yPred))
```

The use of `ones_like` with `cumsum` allows you to use this loss function to any kind of `(samples,classes)` outputs.

---

Hint: always use [backend functions](https://keras.io/backend/) when working with tensors. You can use slices, but avoid iterating.

Comment: I spent hours trying to figure this out. Thank you!

Comment: In `(1/idx)*K.square(yTrue-yPred)`, is `*` elementwise operation or vector-matrix multiplication operation?  Thanks!

Comment: It's elementwise. For matrix multiplication there are `K.dot()` and `K.batch_dot()`.

Comment: @DanielMöller Thanks!  But `K.square(yTrue-yPred)` has shape (n_samples, n_components), while `1/idx` has shape (n_components,), how does elementwise multiplication work in this case?

Comment: @username123, the missing dimension (n_samples) will be repeated.

Comment: @DanielMöller  What if we want to put weights of shape (n_shapes, ) on dimension of (n_samples) (i.e. put different weights on different samples), what operation do we use then?

Comment: Can you be more specific?? There are so many possibilities of "how" you want these weights.